# Cant import chatterbot

Tags: python

When I try to `import input_function from chatterbot.utils` I get this error

```
Unresolved attribute reference 'default_session' for class 'ChatBot'
```

I can't find a solution. The file is blank with only the import statement

and the complete error is:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'input_function' from 'chatterbot.utils' (/Users/drax/Desktop/utils.py)

Unresolved attribute reference 'default_session' for class 'ChatBot'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The chatterbot.utils is deprecated.
Change it with this:

```
from chatterbot.conversation import Statement
```

And check [here](https://github.com/gunthercox/ChatterBot/blob/4ff8af28567ed446ae796d37c246bb6a14032fe7/examples/learning_feedback_example.py)